# How to store date in SharedPreference?

Tags: android, date, logic, sharedpreferences

I want an app to do particular thing once in a day, when user opens the app first time in day.
To do so I want to store a date in SharedPreference.
But it only stores int, boolean, string etc.

```
/*

I'm showing my logic here. If there is better way plz tell me!!!
I will give some by default value like 00/00/0000 for initialization.
The first time user starts the app then I will do that particular work and initialize sharedPreference by current date 16/03/2020. 
If user again opens app by same date I don't do that work(By checking curdate and sharedPreference date).
If user opens app on another date I check currentDate and sharedPreference date, if they are different I will do that work and edit the sharedPreference by that day.
*/
```

So tell me how can store date in sharedPreference?

Comment: Convert date toString

Comment: Save time in milliseconds

Comment: Plz open my question. My problem is different!!!

Comment: @Aayushdual if you believe your question is different, [edit] your question to explain exactly how it is different from the marked duplicate.  This will allow people to vote to reopen.

Comment: Ok thx for that!! I waited 90 minutes to ask again!!

Answer (score 0):

You can store date as timestamp:

```
long timest = (new Date()).getTime();
// save it to Preferences as Long
```

and then read it and convert to `Date` again:

```
long timest = // read from Preferences as Long
Date date = new Date(timest);
```